# How to show column each stage in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

I need query data in azure devops for get every changed date in every stage in devops (like new to--> in progress --> to closed status) including change date for each stage

There are column show in devops query but only last stage

For example stage new in query is in 14 august, change to in progress is 15  august, how to get it using query for all task in devops..

Answer (score 0):

> How to show column each stage in azure devops

For this issue ,I am afraid it is currently not support in azure devops. No such column can display all the states of each stage of the item.

If you want to view all the states of each stage of the item ,you can view the history of work items . For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/history-and-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).

[image]